# Nagios monitoring ok but SSL Handshake error

Tags: nagios

Good Folks,

I have a weird situation here. My remote linux server is nice monitored by Nagios but when I try to run check_nrpe -H  I get SSL Handshake error. I don't the same error from Nagios server.

```
[code]
[root@agent1 ~]# /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H master
CHECK_NRPE: Error - Could not complete SSL handshake.
[root@agent1 ~]# 
[root@master ~]# /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H agent1
NRPE v2.15
[root@master ~]# 
[/code]
```

Any idea how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Check your nrpe configuration file and your IP in only_from list.

```
nano /etc/xinetd.d/nrpe 
        # default: on
        # description: NRPE (Nagios Remote Plugin Executor)
service nrpe
         {
            flags = REUSE
            socket_type = stream
            port = 5666
            wait = no
            user = nagios
            group = nagios
            server = /usr/local/nagios/bin/nrpe
            server_args = -c /usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg --inetd
            log_on_failure += USERID
            disable = no
            only_from = IP1 IP2 IP3
}
```

Comment: I already checked that Sir before posting, It has IP of Nagios Server.

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer is recompiling nrpe with ssl headers.

```
./configure --enable-ssl
```

Rest steps which are given in everywhere in general documentation are correct.